# Would putting turbines on trains to utilize the Bernoulli-induced winds around trains work?

Tags: thermodynamics

I'm assuming since trains move so fast, there are Bernoulli effect-induced winds happening around it, with the direction perpendicular to the body (is this true?).

If I were to put wind turbines on a train whose axes are perpendicular to the body of the train to utilize the Bernoulli-induced winds, would I be doing something useful or would I just be converting train-fuel to electricity with an unnecessary extra step?

Thanks!

EDIT: my thought process is that the Bernoulli effect wouldn't have been present if the train had no drag in the first place, so I'm just using energy from that inefficiency, rather than creating an infinite motion machine.

Answer (score 2):

I think the question is asking something more than is correctly stated in the answer from niels nielsen.

Bernoulli effect does not induce any wind, and thus there is no flow. If you want to produce energy, you need Pressure and flow. But this effect doesn't produce any flow.
This is the flow out of the wake, when this vacuum is produced, but once the vacuum is created, it's only maintained without any further flow. If you enter to this low pressure region, you are pushed towards it from the high pressure side; But this flow is always some distance a way from your train surfaces. Any anything installed to there would be on the vacuum.
Nothing would move there.

Look this video;
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K0aPuLn76H0
(Picture is from the video.)

[image: Bernoulli effect]

Bernoulli effect can hold the mass on its place, but that's it. No mass is moving, so no work is done.

Comment: But wouldn’t there be wind from the high pressure area to the low pressure area?

Comment: @MehranJ No, the reason why there is this low pressure area is, that there is "wind" away from the wake when the train starts to move. But after this low pressure is created there is no "wind". Then the Train stops, there is "wind" which fills this area. But that's it. this doesn't change the fact that if there is some object on the pressure-change region, it will be moving because of these pressure differences. But when it's just gas, there is no such "wind".  There is always some circulation inside the wake, but that has no energy in any practical sense.

Comment: Aha!  Thank you.  So would placing pistons, for example, that push in when the train is moving and go out when the train is stopped work?

Comment: @MehranJ Yes, they actually would work. But the energy amount would be small, as there would be only one cycle of piston volume.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking from the  train's frame of reference .

A person on the  train will see winds blowing in direction exactly opposite to the trains direction of motion (*to the observer all the air around the train appears to flow backwards*) . There's no way the turbines you described  ( those fitted outside the train) would  rotate.
But turbines if fitted in the windows will rotate .
The open  windows increase the air drag.

By installing turbines in  windows you will be "gaining energy from the inefficiency " but don't you think sealing the windows all together to increase the efficiency by reducing the drag is a way better method.